# Ordering Inside of Array and put null or 0 for missing values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having problem to order inside of an array due to the missing or null values.

My code

```
SELECT
submission_id,
ARRAY_AGG(question_score) as questions_scores,
SUM(question_score) as groupe_score

FROM(
SELECT
sa.submission_id,
qq.id as question_id,
CASE WHEN SUM(qo.answer_points) > MAX(qq.max_answer_points) THEN MAX(qq.max_answer_points) ELSE SUM(qo.answer_points) END as question_score
FROM selection_answers sa
    inner join question_options qo on qo.id = sa.question_option_id
    inner join questions qq on qq.id = qo.question_id
WHERE qq.task_form_id = 3306 GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY sa.submission_id ASC, qq.id ASC ) AS t1 GROUP BY 1
```

Output:

```
  submission_id |         questions_scores           |  groupe_score
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
    1034543     | {0,0,0,10,0,10,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,0}          |  30
    1034562     | {0,15,15,5,10,0,10,0,5,0,10,10,5,0,0}      |  85
    1034645     | {0,0,10,0,10,0,5,0,10,10,5,0,0}            |  50
    1034699     | {0,0,0,15,5,10,0,10,0,5,0,0,10,10,5,0,0,0} |  70
```

I need same number of output inside questions_scores in the same qq.id order. I've tried left and full outer join but could not find a way. Also I've created a CTE with question table and tried to join for each row in this table and CTE but could not figure it out. Thanks for your help!

------- edit for table details---- 
question table columns:

```
id | max_answer_points
```

question_options table columns:

```
id | question_id | answer_points
```

selection_answer table columns:

```
id| submission_id| question_option_id
```

when a submission submitted there can be multiple options selected in selected_answers or there might be no answers since question is jumped due to the logic related with a result of the previous selected question. What I aim is to show SUM(answer_points) grouped by submission and show inside of an array score of each question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *same number of output inside questions_scores*. Can you explain, maybe with an example?

Comment: Hi Laurenz,  I mean in first submissions there are 15 output. Due the logic jump on questions some submissions has 15 questions answered, some has 13 etc like first and third row in sample. I need 15 score on each questions_scores.

Comment: You want a score for every question, even if there is no matching `selection_answers` or `question_options`?

Comment: Yes, 0 or it can be empty comma separeted like" 0,15,,5,0,,5 ".
I do join like SELECT FROM questions left join questions options left join selection_answers still cannot get what I want.

Comment: It would help to understand / reproduce the problem if you would complete your post with the 3 table's definitions along with test data!

Comment: I added details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved. I selected questions table two times then joined selection_answers and question_options into one of them. Here is the code:

```
SELECT
submission_id,
ARRAY_AGG(question_score) as question_scores,
SUM(question_score) as total_score
FROM(
SELECT
submission_id, qq_id,
SUM(CASE WHEN qq_id=xx_id THEN question_score ELSE 0 END) AS question_score
FROM (
 SELECT
 qq.id as qq_id,
 xx.id as xx_id,
 sa.submission_id,
 CASE WHEN SUM(qo.answer_points) > MAX(xx.max_answer_points) THEN MAX(xx.max_answer_points) ELSE SUM(qo.answer_points) END as question_score
 FROM questions qq, questions xx
     left join question_options qo on qo.question_id = xx.id
     left join selection_answers sa on sa.question_option_id = qo.id
     left join task_forms tf on tf.id = xx.task_form_id
 WHERE qq.task_form_id=3306  AND  xx.task_form_id=3306 
 GROUP BY 1,2,3  ORDER BY sa.submission_id ASC, qq.position ASC, xx.position ASC ) AS t1 GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC ) AS t2
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a result for every `questions` and every `submission_answers`, regardless if there is a matching `question_options` or not.

In that case you should join like this:

```
FROM (submission_answers sa
      CROSS JOIN questions qq)
     LEFT JOIN question_options qo
        ON qo.id = sa.question_option_id AND qo.question_id = qq.id
```

You'll have to deal with the NULL values in your query.

To get the correct ordering in the array, use

```
array_agg(question_score ORDER BY qq.id) as questions_scores
```

Comment: I tried with cross join but could not do . What if I use dense_rank for questions and join with this rank question table again to the query? I can't think straight.

Comment: Can you clarify "but could not do"?